# GWT. Add dominant css style to element without overriding native style

Tags: java, gwt

How to add CSS class to widget, without overriding ALL gwt's attributes, but overriding only those attributes that exist in my style?

When I use

`addStyleName('myCss')`  - then gwt's native styles are dominant, and my styles don't apply if they are exist in native GWT style..

When I use

`setStyleName` or `setPrimaryStyleName` then all native GWT styles are drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want some of the styles from a rule to override GWT default styles, you can add `!important` to them in your CSS rule.

Example:

```
.myStyle {
  border-width: 3px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fighting specificity. Here is an excellent explanation on [how specificity works](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).

I really recommend against `!important` rules since they merely cause you to keep leapfrogging each other in declaring rules.

Instead, I'd recommend using both rules like so:

```
.gwt-Label.myCss {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```